# Connecting to a network that blocks non-computer devices with Galaxy S4

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, networking

I would like to connect my Galaxy S4 to my school's WiFi network in order to cut down on expensive data usage. The problem is that some mobile devices (including my phone) can't connect, so I can't access the internet. I have the same problem at my house, where every 24 hours anything that isn't a computer gets kicked off and I need to reset the router. I am trying to find a way to fix this with all networks that have this issue (from my phone, as I can't modify the servers at my school). Since my phone is rooted, I can edit system files, so if I could modify my phone so that the signals sent to the network I am trying to connect to appear to be coming from a computer, I could be able to connect. Are there system files that I could modify to achieve this, or is it more hardwired into my phone? Note: I would only like to modify my phone's files, so that it is detected as a computer and not a phone. Mobile features may need to be disabled for this, so that it can technically be considered as a computer by the network.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Hacking the school's network for unauthorised internet access. If they don't want you accessing the Internet via their WiFi then you won't be able to outside of brute force hacking your way into it which is not advised and completely illegal in most parts of the world.

Comment: I know this doesn't require hacking with brute force. Brute force is for cracking passwords, and this network is not password-protected. It only requires changing the signatures coming from my phone. This requires no hacking-- nothing illegal, and nothing even against school rules. There is no rule saying phones aren't allowed to connect to the network, but for some reason they are blocked.

Comment: Yes, there is such a rule: the owner of a network has full authority on it. Tricking your way in without allowance is called "hacking", and it's abusing someone else's property. They're making the rules. If I were the network admin, I'd additionally implement additional measures such as MAC filters (to only allow "known devices" in) – which might even be the way how they detect mobile devices in the first place, as their MAC addresses first fields might reveal this fact.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is not illegal; he's *not* looking for WPA cracking or the like.  If there is any sort of agreement between the school and users of its Wi-Fi, it doesn't involve us.  This ultimately seems no different from changing a user agent, which we would support here for Android browsers.

Comment: Except, we don't even know what blocks the connection on mobile, and thus making it unclear. First, you mentioned "*some mobile devices (including my phone) can't connect*", does it mean that there *are* mobile devices that can connect and use its connection? Anyway, why didn't you ask their IT service if it's possible for your device to connect? AFAIK, for browsing, the only thing that can differentiate between PC or mobile is user-agent. Other than that, it would be related to hardware ID (e.g. MAC address, as mentioned on Izzy's comment)

Comment: Some iPods can connect. I don't know about smartphones. But if what is being used to block me is my MAC address or user agent, how could I change them to appear as a computer?